# Ternary the operator inside the button and call the function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to set the `ternary operator` and call the `start()` function. Under the influence of data from API, `pending` will change to`true`.
I am trying to use the ternary operator inside the button and initiate the click event. `Pending = true` call the click event, the`start ()`function.

`{this.state.pending ? this.start() : null}`

```
class Button extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      isRunning: false,
            pending: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get
            axios({
                url: "https://app/api/v1/running",
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`           
                }
            })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);   
                    this.setState({
                        pending: response.data.pending   //true
                    });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            })
  }

    start = () => {
        console.log('AAAA');
  }

  render () {
    return (
            <button {this.state.pending ? this.start() : null} onClick={this.start}>
                Start
            </button> 
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not call the start function on api response success ?

Comment: Can you be more specific in what case do you want to call `start()` function?

Comment: @jank When I retrieve data from the server. `Pending` changes to `true`. The button starts itself.

Comment: @ShocKwav3_   give me axample, please

Comment: @ShocKwav3_ start it in on successful request `.then(response => this.start())` since this is what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @Umbro I have added two examples in the answer :)

Comment: Yes, thanks @jank that's what I meant in my earlier comment

Answer (score 0):

You could take one of two approaches here.

**1. Run the function straight from the api response success callback**

```
.then(response => {
                console.log(response);   
                    this.setState({
                        pending: response.data.pending   //true
                    });
                this.start();             //Here
            })
```

If you want to update the state before calling that function in any case then simply call the function in the callback of `setState`s second parameter. `setState` also accepts a function as its parameter and executes that function **after** performing the update. This is important to remember because `setState` operates asynchronously. So, If you want to make sure before your call the value has to update for some reason you can do this way. More about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

```
.then(response => {
                    console.log(response);   
                        this.setState({
                            pending: response.data.pending   //true
                        }, this.start);
            })
```

**2. Use a component lifecycle method to listen for state changes and run the function**

```
componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState) => {
  if(prevState.pending === false && this.state.pending === true){
    this.start()
  }
}
```

Every time you have a state or prop change componentDidUpdate executes. Note that it does not update when the component first mounts. And from the look of your code since `pending` is local to this component only you don't need to capture the case when it mounts firsts. More reference on lifecycle methods: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Hope that clears your confusion here. Cheers!

Comment: @ShockKwav3_   And what if I have  `this.setState ({ results: response.data;
pending: response.data.pending // true
 }, () => {
 this.start (); // Here
                         });`

Comment: It would't solve your case because the `response.data.pending` can be `false` coming from the api. We do not know what value it will hold. Regardless of it's value `this.start()` will execute after state update which is wrong because we want it for only `true`. So in that case I recommend the 2nd option in my answer, with `componentDidUpdate` but It depends on your overall use case. If you know `response.data.pending` will always have true in successful response then you can proceed with 1st solution but 2nd one does the same with extra safety

Comment: @ShockKwav3_   `this.setState({
                            results: response.data; pending: response.data.pending   //true
                        }, this.start);`   results --> true; pending --> false; this.start call or not ?

Comment: It will call `this.start` no matter what value is there. true or false both. If you don't care about the value you can do this but if you want it to happen only when true then use `componentDidUpdate` approach